# Select certain months in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select students within a MYSQL database where their dates of birth are in certain months (May, June or July) here is what I think the command is:

```
SELECT studentid, fName, lName, dob
WHERE MONTH(dob)='5'
FROM student;
```

Here is an example of a records:
[image: Example of records image]

However I put this in the PHPmyadmin sql box and it returns an error:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE MONTH(dob)='5' FROM student LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

The field type is date. MySQL version is 5.1.41.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Move the `FROM` before the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT studentid, fName, lName, dob
FROM student
WHERE MONTH(dob)='5'
```

Comment: @Simon -- np, glad I could help!  Cheers!

Comment: Is the OR statement the best way to handle the other months?
SELECT studentid, fName, lName, dob
FROM student
WHERE MONTH(dob)='5' OR MONTH(dob)='6' OR MONTH(dob)='7';

Comment: You could use an `IN` clause for that.  Also you could drop the single quotes since the MONTH function returns an integer value.